# How do I check in JAVA if a string is not equal to?

Tags: java, logical-operators

How do I check in Java if a string is not equal to "ABC"?

I know that to check if it is equal we can type `string.equals("ABC")` but how do I do it when I want to check if it is **not** equal?

Comment: `!string.equal("ABC") `

Comment: You need to read a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negate the returning value from `string.equals(TestString)`:

```
!string.equals("ABC")
```

You better have a look at [Logical Operators in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Answer (score 2):

Simply negate the result of `equals`:

`!string.equals("ABC")`

`String.equals` returns a `boolean` value, to get the inverse of any boolean value, use the `!` operator:

```
boolean t = true; // t will be true
boolean f = !t; // f will be false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write it like this.
`!string.equals("ABC")`